# How to add "columnDefs" , if the column exists?

Tags: datatables-1.10

I want to add columnDefs before initializing datatable, only if the column exists. How do i add the if else check?

I want do something like this

```
if(columnexists)
    $('#dailyReportTable').dataTable().append(columnDefs)
else
    $('#dailyReportTable').dataTable().append(Someother_columnDefs)
```